# Expressjs static javascript file not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, create-react-app

I'm setting up express server with create-react-app.

AT console I'm getting

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                    bundle.js:1`

When I click on error it shows me homepage html. 
While using morgan logger its giving me 200 ok.

`GET /static/js/bundle.js 304 1.145 ms - -`

Also when i view source click on css link it shows me css while click on javascript link it shows me blank page(homepage html).

Here is the the server code.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var path = require ('path');

var data = {};


express()
    .use(logger('dev'))
    .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'flashcard-app/build')))

    .use(bodyParser.json())
    .get('/api/test', (req, res) => res.json("Great news every thing is working fine."))
    .get('/api/data', (req, res) => res.json(data))
    .post('/api/data', (req, res) => res.json(data = req.body))
    .get('*', function(req, res) {
        console.log('serving path:', path.join(__dirname+'/flashcard-app/build/index.html'));
         res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'flashcard-app/build/index.html'));
    })
    .listen(3333, function(){
        console.log('server running at 3333');
    });
```

Also this is custom server.js file not one that provided by express-generator. I'm running by `node server_old.js` instead of using `./bin/www`

Help comment tips appreciated.

[image: folder-structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fetch `/static/js/bundle.js`, but there is no `bundle.js` in `static/js`.

I think you are trying to use `index.html` that tries to `bundle.js` while your webpack config builds `main.[hash].js`

Comment: working perfectly. previously while debugging i hardcoded in src files which was exactly produced by react build. actually it is picking files from manifest.json where original path is "main.js": "static/js/main.4c2d71c3.js",